# How to install WebIDL Ubuntu

Tags: python, node.js, npm, emscripten, webidl

Hello I am trying to build a library using emscripten.
I am encountering an error

```
python /usr/share/emscripten/tools/webidl_binder.py liquidfun.idl liquidfun_glue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/tools/webidl_binder.py", line 15, in <module>
    import WebIDL
ImportError: No module named WebIDL
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'liquidfun_glue.cpp' failed
make: *** [liquidfun_glue.cpp] Error 1
```

If the module WebIDL cannot be found how do I install it?

I tried npm-instll webidl but that just created a node-modules folder with it in the make directory. Where should I install it to if i want it to work?

EDIT: I've been doing some reading and it seems to be a python thing. I still don't know how to install WebIDL python module though.